# Error in numeric(nrowz) : invalid 'length' argument from map() function

Tags: r

I am trying to draw a map with the `map()` function but it returns an error that I can not solve.

With

```
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
map('worldHires')
```

I get this error:

> ```
> Error in numeric(nrowz) : invalid 'length' argument
> ```

Comment: Hi There, this error usually occurs when there are null or NA values in your dataset, however, without either sample code or data it would be very hard to be sure. You can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38159024/invalid-length-argument-error?rq=1

Comment: At the moment I do not use my data yet. The 'worldHires' argument is in the mapdata library.

Answer (score 4):

This may help (or perhaps help someone with a similar question).  I had the same error - though I may have had a different problem.  For me, there was a conflict between maps::map() and purrr::map() functions.  I was trying to use map() from *purrr* but it had been masked by map() from *maps*.  I solved it by explicitly referencing which package library's map() function I wanted to call, which in my case was "purrr::map()".